# Set <a> to display none

Tags: javascript, dom

Here is my HTML:

```
<td>
  <a class="link" href="#">
   <span class="download">Link</span>
  </a>
  <a class="link" href="#">
    <span class="csvdownload">Link 2</span>
  </a>
</td>
```

I need to set this CSS:

```
a.link {
  display: none;
}
```

But only to the `<a>` that contains the span with the class `csvdownload`

Ideally need to do this strictly with javascript not a plugin like jQuery...

Comment: About doing this with JavaScript: everything that can be done with jQuery, can be done natively in JavaScript, as jQuery is merely a framework.

Answer (score 2):

If you have control over the markup, this would be much better:

```
<td>
  <a class="download" href="#">Link</a>
  <a class="csvdownload" href="#">Link 2</a>
</td>
```

You already know that the `<a>` tags are "links" so adding that CSS class is redundant (replace any CSS rules using .link to simply use a).  Then hide your links setting `display:none` on the .csvdownload class directly.

If you still need the "link" class to differentiate them from other anchors, you can simply have both classes:

```
<td>
  <a class="link download" href="#">Link</a>
  <a class="link csvdownload" href="#">Link 2</a>
</td>
```

Comment: How about CSS selectors?

a + span:#csvdownload{display:none} or something like that

Comment: There are various ways to do it with the existing markup.  My point is that I doubt it really needs to be that complicated.  Also, the + selector is known to be problematic in most versions of IE (does not work at all in IE6).

Answer (score 1):

```
var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
for (var i=0,n=spans.length;i<n;i++) {
  if (spans[i].className=="csvdownload") {
    spans[i].parentNode.style.display='none';
    break;
  }
}
```

You may need to test the textnode in FF

Comment: as seen here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398816/how-to-handle-firefox-inserting-text-elements-between-tags

Answer (score 0):

To expand on the previous answer, you could also use:

```
var byClass = document.getElementsByClassName,
    el;
if (byClass) {
    el = byClass('cvsdownload');
} else {
    var spans = document.getElementsByTagName('span');
    for (var i = 0, n = spans.length; i < n; i++) {
        if (spans[i].className == "csvdownload") {
            el = spans[i];
            break;
        }
    }
}
if (el) {
    el.parentNode.style.display = 'none';
}
```

It's generally quicker to use the built in methods where possible.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have no CSS rules attached to `a.link` that would impart width/height in the absence of content, simply setting `display: none;` to `span.csvdownload` should effectively achieve the same thing as hiding its parent element. You would not even need Javascript, just add it to your stylesheet.